# Replace a nested LaTeX command with multiple arguments

Tags: macros, environments

I'd like to replace the LaTeX command `\teilseiten{left col width}{left col text}{right col text}` by an nested environment. The problem is, that the second and third argument of `\teilseiten` contains commands and/or environments.

```
\teilseiten{0.5}{
  Some text and \textbf{even}
  \begin{center}
     environments
  \end{center}
}{
  Some other text and \textbf{even}
  \begin{center}
    more environments
  \end{center}
}
```

Should be replaced whith

```
\begin{mycolumns}
  \begin{mycolumn}{0.5}
    Some text and \textbf{even}
    \begin{center}
       environments
    \end{center}
  \end{mycolumn}
  \begin{mycolumn}{0.5}
    Some other text and \textbf{even}
    \begin{center}
       more environments
    \end{center}
  \end{mycolumn}
\end{mycolumns}
```

Does anybody know how to achieve this? I am not looking for a redefinition of the `\teilseiten`-command. I want to batch-replace this in every file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `tiny` isn't really an environment. What do you mean by `batch replacement`?`

Comment: That's not a tex question. Use whatever language you want which offers search and replace (perl, ...).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I mean replacing it with sed or some sophisticated linux tool.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I know, but the guys over at superuser.com told me to ask it here ;-)

Comment: @Simon they must have misunderstood the question as it is off topic here. Any editor with regex support (surely most?) should be able to do this

Comment: Then they misunderstood the question. Redefining `\teilseiten` is a tex question, replacing it not. And if it can be done depends on the document. *If* the middle part `}{` and the end brace is always alone on a line it is rather straightforward. It could be fiddly if there is other tex code ...